# Replace Hexadecimal back to original string text

Tags: c#, xml, string, hex

using following method to replace invalid xml characters before calling XDocument.LoadXml in Web Service as:

```
[WebMethod]
public XmlDocument GetXml(string text)
{
    XElement xElement = new XElement("RootNode");
    xElement.Add(new XElement("title", SanitizeHexaDecimalSymbol(text))
    var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc .LoadXml(xElement.Tostring())
}

private static string SanitizeHexaDecimalSymbol(string txt)
{
   string regEx = "[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x26]";
   return Regex.Replace(text, regEx, "", RegexOptions.Compiled);
}
```

How do I have replace back the sanitized text to its original text.
I don't want to use hard code way to replace text back to its original text.

Is there a method where i can call as DesanitizeHexaDecimalSymbol(text) method, I'm not sure what would be the implementation inside this method to get back original text.

Solution:
I followed the @Zohar Solution to make it as a work around for replacing back the original text from the hexadexcmal symbol.

Comment: I can't see how you will be able to do it.

Comment: Basically when I can replace text with following hexadecimal Symbol like "[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x26]", i need to know corresponding text value for hexadecimal symbol to replace back to original text.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't this row **Regex.Replace(text, regEx, "", RegexOptions.Compiled);** replaces all the characters matching your pattern to empty strings?

If that is the case, the only way to have the original string back is to keep it in some variable outside this function.
I'm guessing you have multiple strings that you send to this function so you will need a Dictionary<XmlDocument, string> to keep all of XmlDocument outcome of this function with it's original string.
This way it's going to be easy to un-sanitize them.

Comment: Thanks @Zohar, yes realized that and handle it accordingly. Though not efficient but it works fine. Thanks for guiding to right path..